# Handling files with spaces in a bash selection menu

Tags: bash, menu, filenames

I am trying to make this script handle file with spaces in them. it is supposed show and execute the content of files in a directory. when I select a file with a space in it, bash fails with bash: foo: no such file or directory, What am I missing to make this handle files correctly

```
# /etc/skel/.bashrc
#Interactive shell detection
if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then
# Shell is non-interactive.  Be done now!
return
fi
#kv-bash (easy) var database & setup of info
echo "type 'menu' for a bash menu"
#done####################
#to easily launch crouton enviroments
addentry() {
cd ~/.sslm
echo "Name your menu entry."
read entry
sleep 1s

if [ -e "$entry " ]
then
echo "Error, Menu entry already exists"
addentry
else
echo "what do you want the entry to do?"
read entryexec
echo "$entryexec && menu"> ~/.sslm/"$entry"
echo "done"
cd ~/
fi 
sleep 1s
}
###################
delentry() {
cd ~/.sslm
ls -x
echo "what entry do you want to delete?"
read del
rm "$del"
echo "the work has been done, he is dead"
}
###################
menu() {
clear
cd ~/.sslm
echo "-- simple shell launcher menu v1.o --"

# set the prompt used by select, replacing "#?"
PS3="Use number to select a file or 'exit' to leave: "

# allow the user to choose a file
select filename in *
do
# leave the loop if the user says 'stop'
if [[ "$REPLY" == exit ]]; then 
cd ~/
break
fi

# complain if no file was selected, and loop to ask again
if [[ "$filename" == "" ]]
then
    echo "'$REPLY' is not a valid number"
sleep 1s
continue
fi

# now we can use the selected file, trying to get it to run the shell 
script
. $filename
# it'll ask for another unless we leave the loop
break
done
}
menu
```

also, this is on a chromebook, so there is no apt.

Comment: Maybe quoting this will help: `. "$filename"`.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: it retuns 'bash: . foo foo2: command not found

Comment: Nevermind, bad formatting on my part.

Answer (score 0):

At this part:

```
  script
. $filename
```

I just needed to change to . "$filename"
thx @PesaThe